# How to change size of canvas drawing for different screen sizes?

Tags: android, canvas, screen, resolution

I am able to draw on canvas. I want to know how to use that canvas for different screen sizes and screen resolutions.can anyone provide method for converting points on canvas to percentage.

Comment: What are you using right now?

Comment: I am using float values for position of objects  now i want to convert that float values  in percentage with screen resolution.

Comment: use `Canvas#concat` or `Canvas#scale`